# TableLayout resizing views on resizing text even though it is fixed size

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have some square TextViews in a TableLayout. I have to resize text programmatically. Cannot use the new "auto-resize", I need to set the text size myself.

So, my approach is to have fixed layout_height and layout_width for the TextViews in the table layout and to use setTextSize in code.

Problem is as soon as text is resized, weird things start happening, and not just to the TextView/cell that is being edited, but the neighboring ones too!

The first time text is resized, the neighboring cell is affected (see image). This happens both on the real phone (API24) and emulator (API 24, 28). The second time text is resized, the second cell goes back to normal on the emulator. On the real device, the first cell is resized again, or the top margin increased.

[image: layout problems]

I tried changing different settings for TableLayout, TableRow, and TextView (wrap_content, min/max Height), but nothing fixes the issue except for commenting out the setTextSize.

I do need to use TableLayout, so replacing this with a different layout is not an option for me.

Why doesn't this work?

To replicate the issue paste below layout and code into a new "empty activity" project. I am using, at the time of writing, the latest software (Android Studio 3.2.1 with compile sdk version API 28, java version 1.8, min sdk version 22.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer">

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#000">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"/>

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>


        <Button
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Click"
            android:id="@+id/button1"/>

   </LinearLayout>
```

My activity code is:

```
package app.howsmydriving.layoutproblem;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private String sContent = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sContent += "A";
                TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                tv.setText(sContent);

                if(sContent.length() < 3) {
                    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 30);
                } else {
                    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 15);
                }
            }

        });
    }



    }
```

Comment: can you try using `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP` instead of `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP`

Comment: Doesn't fix it. I am starting to think it is a bug in table layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to understand is what `android:baselineAligned` actually means.

This attribute is set to `true` by default, and controls the vertical positioning of sibling `TextView`s inside a horizontal `LinearLayout`. The `TextView`s will be pushed up or down as necessary to make sure that all text baselines (the imaginary line the text is sitting on) line up.

[image]

The next thing to realize is that `TableRow` is a subclass of `LinearLayout`, and is horizontal.

So, if you want full control over the vertical positioning of the `TextView`s inside your `TableRow`, you should set `android:baselineAligned="false"` to avoid having the system override you.

[image]

## Edit

The dimensions of the `TextView` have no effect on baseline alignment; the `LinearLayout` will both (a) move the `TextView`s themselves up and down as necessary and (b) move the text *within* the `TextView` up and down as necessary to make sure that the baselines align.

Here's a demo. I've set background colors to make everything very obvious. The parent `LinearLayout` has a fixed height of `100dp`, the first `TextView` is `wrap_content`, the second is `40dp` (bigger than it needs to be), and the third is `16dp` (smaller than it needs to be).

[image]

This is all in service of making sure that the baselines line up. The `LinearLayout` will do whatever it needs to to make this happen, unless you disable baseline alignment.

Comment: That would make sense if textView was set to wrap_content, but when the textView height is fixed this should not happen. While troubleshooting, I was looking at top margin and layout height values and they were not changing. I did notice padding value changing from -10 to -6. Seems that text size affects padding when baseline align is ON which looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @under see my edit. TextView dimensions have no effect on baseline alignment.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by switching off baselineAligned for LinearLayout, TableLayout and TableRow:

```
android:baselineAligned="false"
```

Not sure why this works, if someone has a better explanation I will accept that as an answer.